# How to manipulate the response from http request method?

Tags: node.js, https, httprequest, sinon

I am using https module with "request" function in node. It sends a response whenever it is called. It sends out a similar response to the below onject

```
{
  _readableState: {
   },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {

  },
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: {},
  connection: {},
  httpVersionMajor: null,
  httpVersionMinor: null,
  httpVersion: null,
  complete: false,
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  rawHeaders: [

  ]
}
```

I have to remove the "header" from it dynamically. How do I do it? I am unit testing with nock and I am able to set headers through .reply method as a third parameter(.reply(200, {}, {//header})) , but unfortunately not bale to remove that tag itself. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly.

If you just want to simply discard the response header.

Just set res.headers value to `undefined` or delete it.

```
delete res.headers;
//Or
res.headers = undefined;
```

Comment: I have a condition like this ----------if(res.headers) {//do something} else {//dosomething}. res is reponse from https.request method. I want to test the else loop, but I have to delete the headers from res before that so that if conditions proves to be false. I hope am clear to u.

Comment: headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }. <--- this tag

Comment: I can set header right as a third parameter to nock().reply({}, {}, //setting header). My question is, is there anyway to delete them(headers)?

Comment: Oh I see!!! 
Sorry maybe I couldn't help you.
There is no way to that without change the module.
If you are going to do that.
You probably have to modify the source code of nock module

Comment: :(. Anything else I can use, to mock http.request and modify the response?

Comment: Just curious about why you need to do it. It's relatively strange to do that.

Comment: Its a requirement. I am writing test cases.